# I am getting Exception Value:No module named views in django

Tags: python, django

I am getting the above error the full trace back is as follows :-

```
ImportError at /login/

No module named views

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    abc.com
Django Version:     1.6
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named views

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 40
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/home/prajakta/.virtualenvs/cptm_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/var/www/cptm/libs',
 '/var/www/cptm/apps',
 '/var/www/cptm',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-5.4.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_ajax_search-1.5.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/goose_extractor-1.0.19-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jieba-0.32-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cssselect-0.9.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pillow-2.5.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client-1.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode',
 '/var/www/cptm/~/.virtualenvs/cptm_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/var/www/cptm',
 '/var/www/cptm/cptm',
 '/var/www/cptm/apps',
 '~/virtualenv/cptm_venv/local/lib/python2.7/django',
 '/var/www/cptm/',
 '/var/www/',
 '/var/www/cptm/',
 '/var/www/']

Server time:    Mon, 21 Jul 2014 23:29:42 +0530
Error during template rendering

In template /var/www/cptm/templates/user_management/sign_in.html, error at line 64
No module named views
54  
55  <body>
56  
57  <div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
58  <div class="container">
59  
60  {% if form.errors %}
61  <p>Your username and password didn`t match. Please try again.</p>
62  {% endif %}
63  
64  <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="{%url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
65  {% csrf_token %}
66  <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
67  <input type="text" name="username" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Username">
68  <input type="password" name="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password">
69  
70  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}"/>
71  <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
72  <a href="#" class="forgotpass pull-right" id="forgotpass">Forgot Your Password?</a>
73  </form>
74
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don’t specify the `login_url` parameter, you’ll need to ensure that the `settings.LOGIN_URL` and your login view are properly associated. For example, using the defaults, add the following line to your URLconf:

```
(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
```

more info at [Using the Django authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/)